# Copy over issue in my linked List

Tags: c++, traversal

I am having an issue with my LLL that I made. For reference, this is supposed to be a class that has pointer to a struct of topic titles which then in turn has a pointer to a LLL of individual posts particular to that topic. My issue is with the else portion of the function, as I can get through the initial part where I make the head and apply a comment within that topic. For some reason, as I have found out through putting cout statements in my code, whatever value I enter as a "post comment" overwrites whatever was previously in the initial spot, and only holds that value.

This may be a dumb error on my part, but I have been looking at this for quite a while and cannot figure out what I did to make that happen. I put a cout statement immediately after else (as you can see) and that outputs the most recently entered topic.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Here is said funcion:

```
int blog::enter(char new_topic[], char new_comment[])
 19 {
 20 
 21     post * new_post = new post;
 22     title * new_thread = new title;
 23     post * temp;
 24     temp = NULL;
 25     title * temp2;
 26     temp2 = NULL;
 27     if(!head)
 28     {
 29 
 30         temp2 = new_thread;
 31         new_thread -> topic = new_topic;
 32         temp2 -> next_topic = NULL;
 33         head = temp2;
 34 
 35         temp2 -> first_post = new_post;
 36         temp = new_post;
 37         temp -> comment = new_comment;
 38         temp -> next = NULL;
 39         return 1;
 40     }
 41     else
 42     {
 43         cout << head -> topic << endl;
 44         temp2 = head;
 45         while(head -> topic != new_topic)
 46         {
 47         cout << "While"<< endl;
 48             temp2 = temp2 -> next_topic;
 49             if(new_topic == temp2 -> topic)
 50             {
 51                 delete new_thread;
 52             }
 53         }
 54         if(!temp2)
 55         {
 56             temp2 = new_thread;
 57             cout << "TEMP2 NEW" << endl;
 58         }
 59         temp = temp2 -> first_post;
 60         cout << "NOLOOP" << endl;
 61 
 62         while(temp)
 63         {
 64             temp = temp -> next;
 65             cout << "WHILE2" << endl;
 66         }
 67 
 68         temp = new_post;
 69         temp -> comment = new_comment;
 70         temp -> next = NULL;
 71         new_post = temp;
 72 
 73 
 74         return 1;
 75     }
 76 }
```

And my header file:

```
  3 #include <iostream>
  4 #include <cstring>
  5 #include <cctype>
  6 using namespace std;
  7 
  8 // stuct to hold the individual posts
  9 
 10 struct post
 11 {
 12 
 13     int rating;
 14     char * comment;
 15     post * next;
 16     post * tail;
 17 
 18 };
 19 
 20 // struct to hold each topic with a pointer to the list of posts underneath that topic
 21 struct title
 22 {
 23 
 24     char * topic;
 25     title * next_topic;
 26     post * first_post;
 27 };
 28 
 29 //class to hold the functions
 30 
 31 class blog
 32 {
 33 
 34     public:
 35 
 36         blog();
 37         ~blog();
 38         int enter(char new_topic[], char new_comment[]);
 39         int display(char new_topic[]);
 40         int display_all();
 41         int rate(char new_topic[], char new_keyword[], int new_rating);
 42         int remove(char new_topic[], char new_keyword[]);
 43 
 44     private:
 45 
 46         title * head;
```

Comment: What is an LLL?  And how is this used in a program?  Are you calling enter() over and over?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are not using std::list?

Comment: A LLL is a linear linked list and it is used in two regards, one of which is to house a group of topics, each of which has a pointer to another list of posts within that topic.  And yes I use a switch statement to call enter any time the user wants to enter a post to a topic.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your blog() constructor initializes head to NULL? 
You are passing enter(..) pointers to external strings, and then keeping those pointers in your structure. 
Where are the original strings stored? 
This class does not store them, it only keeps pointers to them. If you use the same buffers to input the topic and comment strings, then you have a lot of pointers pointing to those buffers, and this might explain the overwrites.
Also, it's best to add constructors to your structs and initialize the members to NULL or an invalid value according to their types. This way you dont have to worry about this part in the main code.
If you actually do not store everything in some external container(s), I suggest you modify your structs and make them cabable of storing the data, and also delete them when the struct instance is destroyed. IN such a case, a better idea is to use std containers like std::string for string storage and std::list to implement your linear lists without pointers.